# How to find the rest between date ranges that overlaps

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, overlap

I have the following mysql table (rooms)

```
id_user_room     username   room_name   date_from        date_to 
    1             mike        A1        2017-02-01       2017-02-10
    2             evans       A2        2017-01-20       2017-01-30
    3             mike        A3        2017-02-16       2017-02-20
    4             mike        A1        2017-03-01       2017-03-18
```

If I want to know the room of Mike between 2017-01-01 and 2017-05-30, I execute the following SQL query.

```
SELECT room_name, date_from, date_to
FROM rooms
WHERE (date_to >= '2017-01-01' AND date_from <= '2017-05-30')
  AND username='Mike'
order by date_to ASC
```

This query gives the following result:

```
room_name     date_from      date_to
A1           2017-02-01     2017-02-10
A3           2017-02-16     2017-02-20
A1           2017-03-01     2017-03-18
```

Is there a way to get the rest (opposite) date ranges? I mean I would like to know the ranges in which Mike was not living in a room. For the specific example the result I would like to get would be the following date ranges:

```
2017-01-01 to 2017-01-31
2017-02-11 to 2017-02-15
2017-02-21 to 2017-02-28
2017-03-19 to 2017-05-30
```

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Why not do this in your PHP?

Comment: How to do it using php, do you have any idea?

Comment: Create a table with all dates in a year, then make left joins to find away dates, then find discontinuities in the result with a self-join on the result. Messy, but creative :)

Comment: Consider 1st month and last month from all date ranges, mike stayed from date ranges given above(total 3 records). He needs, those date ranges, when he doesn't stay. Am I clear ?

Comment: Maybe the result you would like to get is not the result you actually need. What do you want it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(username VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,room_name CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,date_from DATE
,date_to DATE
,PRIMARY KEY  (username,room_name,date_from)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('mike','A1','2017-02-01','2017-02-10'),
('evans','A2','2017-01-20','2017-01-30'),
('mike','A3','2017-02-16','2017-02-20'),
('mike','A1','2017-03-01','2017-03-18');

     SELECT username
          , '2017-01-01' date_from
          , MIN(date_from - INTERVAL 1 DAY) date_to 
       FROM my_table 
      GROUP 
         BY username
      UNION
     SELECT x.username
         , x.date_to + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         , MIN(y.date_from - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
       FROM my_table x
       JOIN my_table y ON y.date_to > x.date_to
        AND y.username = x.username
      GROUP 
         BY x.username
          , x.date_to
      UNION
     SELECT username
          , MAX(date_to + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
          , '2017-05-30'
       FROM my_table 
      GROUP 
         BY username;
+----------+------------+------------+
| username | date_from  | date_to    |
+----------+------------+------------+
| evans    | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-19 |
| mike     | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-31 |
| mike     | 2017-02-11 | 2017-02-15 |
| mike     | 2017-02-21 | 2017-02-28 |
| evans    | 2017-01-31 | 2017-05-30 |
| mike     | 2017-03-19 | 2017-05-30 |
+----------+------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This assumes that all dates fall within the threshold - but it's not an especially complicated tweak if they don't.

Comment: Strawberry, THANKS a lot for your solution! It gives me exactly what I want, in an efficient way!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create the rooms table, described above:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    id_user_room INTEGER,
    username     CHAR(10),
    room_name    CHAR(10),
    date_from    TIMESTAMP,
    date_to      TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO rooms (id_user_room, username, room_name, date_from, date_to) VALUES
(1, 'mike', 'A1', '2017-02-01', '2017-02-10'),
(2, 'evans', 'A2', '2017-01-20', '2017-01-30'),
(3, 'mike', 'A3', '2017-02-16', '2017-02-20'),
(4, 'mike', 'A1', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-18')
;
```

You have to create an auxilary date table, something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
    day      TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO dates (day) VALUES
('2017-01-01'),
('2017-01-02'),
('2017-01-03'),
...
('2017-12-29'),
('2017-12-30'),
('2017-12-31')
;
```

With this you can find the dates on which Mike was not living in a room:

```
CREATE TABLE empty_dates AS
SELECT
    d.day
FROM
    dates d
LEFT JOIN
    rooms r ON r.username = 'mike' AND d.day BETWEEN r.date_from AND r.date_to
WHERE
  r.id_user_room IS NULL
;
```

For the sake of brevity I materialized this query instead of using subqueries. In other SQL languages, like TSQL or PostgreSQL I would rather use CTE. Now you can specify the intervals' start and end date with joining this table to itself.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ed3.day IS NULL THEN 'Start date' ELSE 'End date' END row_type,
    ed1.day
FROM
    empty_dates ed1
LEFT JOIN
    empty_dates ed2 ON DATEDIFF(ed2.day, ed1.day) = 1
LEFT JOIN
    empty_dates ed3 ON DATEDIFF(ed3.day, ed1.day) = -1
WHERE
    -- the next date is in the rooms table
    ed2.day IS NULL
    -- the previous date is in the rooms table
    OR ed3.day IS NULL
;
```